# RootView Controller are shown shorty when state restorating

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, state-restoration

I use the state restoration offered by the SDK.

I load all my view controllers from the storyboard. The initial view controller shows another view controller modally. Both have a restoration identifier.

The restoration works fine BUT: When I am in the modally presented view controller and press home (save the state). Then reopen the app and state restoration starts the following happens:

For a split second I see the initial view controller and then the screen changes to the modally presented controller which I actually want to see.

Why is this happening? The snapshot in the caches directory does show the correct screen (from the presented view controller).

You can reproduce the issue with [this project](https://github.com/forcha/RestorePresentedIssue). Add a breakpoint in the initial view controller's viewDidAppear method and when restoring state, you will see initial view controller's view in the screen and in view hierarchy:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x155607f0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15560d20>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1555f4f0>>
   | <UIView: 0x15542ad0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x15542a70>>
   |    | <UIButton: 0x155432d0; frame = (137 269; 46 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x15543b30>>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x15663dd0; frame = (0 6; 46 18); text = 'Button'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1566da20>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x15542b60; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x15542fe0>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x15541060; frame = (0 480; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x155410d0>>
```

If you check view controller hierarchy, modally presented view controller is not in initial view controller presented property:

```
(lldb) po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] presentedViewController]
 nil
```

and breakpoint is after (theoretically) state restoration. But later it will be set correctly.

Comment: Actually there is no code. Only the Application delegate methods returning yes. Everthing else is working implicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That issue seems to happen when working with storyboards where you let the framework call `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` for you and it is happening after restoration.

If you add next line to `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

it will fix it.

Comment: That was the issue I was having. Quick and easy fix.